# Array Duplicate Item Filtering by Element Value

Tags: php, array, xml

I'm learning to code PHP and gave myself a challenge: Filter array data by matching a specific element value for duplication. I went through it logically on paper then wrote code and it worked on the first try :) But I bet it is the most inefficient way, so to learn I would like to compare it against what others would do. Below is my code. The array is just a few elements with keys like *name* and *id*. My result is a list of only items with unique ids from an array with many duplicate ids but different names.

Also, part of the challenge was testing XML, JSON, and Arrays so I made the original data XML and used SimpleXML but made a copy of that data as a PHP array and worked with that to do filtering (XPath challenge next).

Thanks for looking and any suggested improvements that I can learn from.

```
//$items is a SimpleXML array of items with name and id elements with many duplicate ids but different names.

//first iteration of id collection
$ids = array();
$countedIds = array();
//convert simplexml array $items to normal array (copy)
$itemsArray = json_decode(json_encode($items), TRUE);           
foreach ($itemsArray as $idItem) 
{
    //collection all ids
    $ids[] = $idItem['id'];     
}
//count number of each id and store in separate array
$countedIds = array_count_values($ids);
#print_r($countedIds);

//start cleaning out duplicates
foreach($itemsArray as $key => &$item)
{
    //clear any whitespace (thanks internets)
    #$thisid = trim($item->id); //if using simplexml
    $thisid = trim($item['id']);
    //check if this id is duplicated (multiple copies) in array
    if($countedIds[$thisid] >1)
    {
        echo $thisid . "item has duplicates (" . $countedIds[$thisid] . ")<br />";
        //add found dupes to separate array
        $dupes[] = $thisid;
        //remove this item from $itemsArray and original $items simplexml array
        unset($itemsArray[$key]);
        unset($items[$key]);
        echo "removed element index " . $key . $item . "<br /><hr>";                    
        //remove this id from $ids array
        unset($ids[$key]);
        //clear out the counted ids
        unset($countedIds);
        //make a fresh array for counting ids
        $countedIds = array();
        //get updated id count
        $countedIds = array_count_values($ids);

        //test simplexml unset?
        #unset($sxe->$this->channel->item);
    }
}       
//review results
print_r($countedIds);
print_r($ids);
print_r($dupes);
print_r($itemsArray);
print_r($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the sole purpose was to have a resultant array of objects that did not have a duplicated id then I would be tempted with the below:

```
// Indexes keyed by item id
$indexes = array();

// Cast to array of objects
$items = current((array)$items);

foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
    $id = ((array)$item)['id'];

    if (isset($indexes[$id])) {
        // Unset this item
        unset($items[$index]);
        // Unset the original instance
        unset($items[$indexes[$id]]);
    } else {
        $indexes[$id] = $index;
    }
}

// List names of items that doesn't have an id that is duplicated
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Still have original SimpleXml object to work with
    echo $item->name . "\n";
}
```